# Angular and p5.js - p5.loadSound is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, p5.js

I have a problem when want to use p5.js in my Angular project.

I use Angular CLI.
Include p5.js in my **.angular-cli.json** file:

```
"scripts": [    
  "../node_modules/p5/lib/p5.min.js",   
  "../node_modules/p5/lib/addons/p5.sound.js",   
  "../node_modules/p5/lib/addons/p5.dom.js"  
],
```

Then in my component I write:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as p5 from 'p5';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-player',
  templateUrl: './player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./player.component.scss']
})
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit {

  play: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const s = (p) => {

      let song;
      let canvas;

      p.preload = () => {
        console.log('preload');
        song = p.loadSound('assets/music/Thunderstruck.mp3');
      }

      p.setup = () => {
        canvas = p.createCanvas(595, 100);
        canvas.parent('equalizer');
        p.background(0);
      }
    }

    let player = new p5(s);

  }

  onPlay() {
    this.play = !this.play;

  }

}
```

And then when I want load my song and use **loadSound()**, JS tells me ***ERROR TypeError: p.loadSound is not a function***

Ok, JS can't find this method in my file, but in browser console I can write something like this:

```
let song = p5.prototype.loadSound('assets/music/Thunderstruck.mp3');
song.play();
```

and everything works ([screenshot of my console](http://prntscr.com/g1jx40))!

I tried to write in my component:

```
song = p.prototype.loadSound('assets/music/Thunderstruck.mp3');
```

It doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps, its just a typescript error, do specify `p` type as `any` like
  `ngOnInit() {
    const s = (p: any) => {`

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work.
Can I iclude p5.js another way?

Comment: Im having the exact same error. Any updates? @Slavik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
import * as p5 from 'p5';
```

*

```
declare var p5: any;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Should I replace "import * as p5 from 'p5';" with "declare var p5: any;" or just the the star to "import declare var p5: any; as p5 from 'p5';". The compiler complains in both cases so I'm definitely missing something from your answer

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea why yet but for me logging `p5sound` just before calling `loadSound` makes it work.

with :

```
import * as p5 from 'p5';
import * as p5sound from 'p5/lib/addons/p5.sound';
```

and :

```
console.log(p5sound)
this.song = s.loadSound('assets/samples/CpW_WetHitE-01.wav');
```