# How to use p5.js in angular 5 application

Tags: angular, angular-cli, p5.js

I have done

```
npm install p5 --save
```

I edited the .angular.cli.json

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/p5/lib/p5.min.js",   
    "../node_modules/p5/lib/addons/p5.sound.js",   
    "../node_modules/p5/lib/addons/p5.dom.js" 
  ]
```

and imported as

```
import * as p5 from 'p5';
```

in app.component.ts file

but now where to add the function setup() and function draw() . I have tried adding it directly but it doesn't work

Comment: maybe they are in the p5 namespace, since you imported * as p5?

Comment: @BrendanWhiting are you saying something like p5.setup();

Comment: Yes, try that. You could also try `import * from 'p5'`

Comment: Actually it is searching for a p5.d.ts file which is not available what should i do

Comment: Not sure if it exists. There seems to be a discussion about it: https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/583. But you shouldn't have to have the type definitions to use the library. I dunno.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [p5.js integration with Angular / not using global functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522496/p5-js-integration-with-angular-not-using-global-functions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45380883/angular-and-p5-js-p5-loadsound-is-not-a-function

Comment: not work for me

Answer (score 10):

**Update:** also works for Angular CLI 7.1.0

> Angular CLI: 6.2.3
>
> Node: 10.9.0

package.json:

`"p5": "^0.7.2"`

import libraries

```
import * as p5 from 'p5';
import "p5/lib/addons/p5.sound";
import "p5/lib/addons/p5.dom";
```

p5 setup

```
ngOnInit() {
    const sketch = (s) => {

      s.preload = () => {
        // preload code
      }

      s.setup = () => {
        s.createCanvas(400, 400);
      };

      s.draw = () => {
        s.background(255);
        s.rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
      };
    }

    let canvas = new p5(sketch);
  }
```

Comment: "When you import p5 dom library in an Angular application..."

Answer (score 8):

That's the way you import it that causes the problem.
You should import it by typing:

```
import 'p5';
```

Then declare a variable:

```
private p5;
```

You should now be able to do something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.createCanvas();
}

private createCanvas() {
  this.p5 = new p5(this.sketch);
}

private sketch(p: any) {
  p.setup = () => {
    p.createCanvas(700, 600);
  };

  p.draw = () => {
    p.background(255);
    p.fill(0);
    p.rect(p.width / 2, p.height / 2, 50, 50);
  };
}
```

Here's my ng version :

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 9.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0
```

and last version of p5 in package.json:

```
 "p5": "^0.6.1"
```

Everything's working fine for me.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you. Better encapsulation here than other examples I have seen.

Answer (score 5):

Found a GitHub repo with examples that show how to import and implement.  It helped fill in what I was missing, how to actually display the canvas.

<https://github.com/avsmips/angular4-p5js-app>

In the template HTML add a div with an ID.

```
<div id="analog-clock-canvas"></div>
```

Then in your component when you create the canvas you can attach it to this div.

```
private drawing = function (p: any) {
p.setup = () => {
  p.createCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight).parent('analog-clock-canvas');
  p.angleMode(p.DEGREES);
  p.rectMode(p.CENTER);
  p.background(0);
};
p.center = { x: 0, y: 0 };
p.draw = () => {
```

Working for me in Angular 7

Answer (score 5):

I have created an abstract class to be able to extend it and work in a simpler way,
example of use:

```
import { P5JSInvoker } from 'src/p5-jsinvoker';

export class RandomWalkerComponent extends P5JSInvoker implements OnInit{

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.startP5JS(document.body);
  }

  setup(p:p5) {
    p.createCanvas(400, 400);
  }

  draw(p:p5) {
    p.stroke(0);
    p.circle(200, 200, 2);
  }
}
```

I pass you the repository
https://github.com/soler1212/P5JSInvoker